# Convert Scientific notation to text or integer using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, scientific-notation

I am looking to convert a scientific notation number into the full integer number.

E.g:

```
8.18234E+11 => 818234011668
```

Excel reformatted all my upc codes within a csv and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/37975/how-can-you-make-excel-2007-stop-formatting-large-numbers-as-scientific-notation) solution is not working for me.

I have my csv open in Notepad++ and would love to do this using a regex find and replace.

Thanks.

Comment: Where should the regex get `011668` from? Note there is information lost.

Comment: @JanDvorak not sure, how does excel convert between the two?

Comment: @corsibu Yes I have the original csv open in excel, however, if I format the column as text, it still shows as sci notation?

Comment: @shnozolla What value is seen in the excel? The rounded one, or the correct one?

Comment: @JanDvorak I am seeing the rounded one in Excel

Comment: @shnozolla Do you have the correct value in any form?

Comment: In that case consider what Jan told you and change the way you view your data in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The damage is already done and cannot be recovered from the CSV file. `8.18234E+11` could be anything* from `818233500000` to `818234499999`.

To prevent Excel from rounding large numbers, you need to store them as text. If you set the cell format to text, any value inserted from then on should be automatically interpreted as text. In OpenOffice Calc (I don't have MS Excel), you can also prefix a numeric value with `'` to get it interpreted as text no matter the cell format.

There is a chance that the correct value is stored in the original XLS (or XSLX or ODS or the live Excel session or ...) file. If not, then you'll have to enter the data again. If the data is there, you need to store it as text or increase the number of significant digits in the exported CSV. If you only have the exported data, then you're out of luck.

*UPC has a single check digit, so only 100 000 out of the 1 000 000 codes are actually valid UPC codes.

Comment: Ok, thanks Jan, that worked nicely. I had to add the data once the column format was changed to 'text'. I would have never guessed.